# Can't install mscviplib package on ubuntu

Tags: python, pip

I can't install mscviplib package on ubuntu, I am using the following command to install it:

```
pip install mscviplib
```

and I got error saying :

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mscviplib (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for mscviplib

Comment: Which python environment are you using?

Comment: This is probably an issue with the environment that you're using.
Try using a different environment like `venv` `pipenv` `poetry`
I would suggest you to use poetry as your choice of python environment.
You can read more about it here:
https://python-poetry.org/

Comment: I can repro on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 Docker image. Perhaps there's a problem on the PyPI side. https://pypi.org/project/mscviplib/ looks like it should be available but I have not investigated further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [[PyPI]: mscviplib **2.211201.122** - Download files](https://pypi.org/project/mscviplib/2.211201.122/#files), the only existing binary is for *Python 3.7 064bit* (and no source package), which implies that the **only *Python* supported version is *v3.7*** (although the same page states):

> **Requires**: Python >=3.7

So, in order to be able to `pip install` that module, you should use *Python 3.7*.

But maybe there are other ways to go. Check [[MS.Docs]: Custom Vision documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service) (which instructs working via a web browser) for more details.